# CSS3 centering animation

Tags: css, animation

1.So my animation is having a flag go down into the middle of the page and then disappearing, but the flag wont go down to the middle using top: 50% and left 50%, I want it to go to the middle by whatever size the browser is.

```
    @-webkit-keyframes brazil-animation
{
0%
{
    width : 200px;
    height : 150px;
    top : 0px;
    left : 0px;
}
80% {
    width: 200px;
    height: 150px;
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0.6;
}
100% {
    width: 200px;
    height: 150px;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    visibility: hidden;
}
}

div.brazil,#brazil {
position: absolute;

-webkit-animation: brazil-animation 5s both 1s linear;
-moz-animation: brazil-animation 5s both 1s linear;
-ms-animation: brazil-animation 5s both 1s linear;
-o-animation: brazil-animation 5s both 1s linear;
animation: brazil-animation 5s both 1s linear;
-webkit-animation-delay: 3s;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use transform or margin

```css
@-webkit-keyframes brazil-animation{
80% {
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0.6;
}
100% {
    top: 50vh;
    left: 50vw;
    transform: translate3d(-100px,-75px,0);
    /*margin: -75px 0 0 -100px;/*margin: height/2 0 0 width/2 but the animation will not be smooth*/
}
}

div.flag {
top:0;
left:0;
width : 200px;
height : 150px;
position: absolute;
background: red;
-webkit-animation: brazil-animation 5s both 3s linear;
}
```

```html
<div class=flag></div>
```

[Fullscreen demo](https://jsfiddle.net/tvgkfaL4/embedded/result/)